# Create distance function between pairs of points

Tags: r, matrix, distance

I want to create a function that takes two pairs of numbers `p1 = (x1, y1)` and `p2 = (x2, y2)` and calculate the distance between them.

What I don't understand is how to define the arguments of the function when it comes pairs of numbers. This is what I have tried but it does not work.

```
Distance <- function (p1=c(x1, y1), p2=c(x2, y2)
```

I am quite sure that I am missing something very basic but I have tried:

```
Distance <- function (p1=c(x1, y1), p2=c(x2, y2){
    return(sqrt(x2-x1)ˆ2 +(y2-y1)ˆ2 )
}
```

It is mainly the argument of the function that I cant make work because it is a pairs of numbers.

Comment: You could do `Distance <- function(p1, p2) sqrt((p1[1] - p2[1])^2 + (p1[2] - p2[2])^2)`

Comment: When I try to write the function it says "x2 is not an object"

Comment: I don't have x2 in the function. Just copy paste my function into your console. Then run `Distance(c(0, 0), c(3, 4))`. It will correctly return `5`

Comment: What @AllanCameron is saying is that your function does not have arguments x1, x2, y1, y2. Its arguments are p1 and p2.